# Facebook share not working(using direct uri)

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to create an fb share button in my website.
When user clicks on button(fb image) it gets redirected to http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=.
 I m setting url as location.href dynamically through js
url is encoded automatically and when i click on button i see http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2F ...
url has a parameter x. it is in the form http://website.com/?x=
after clicking i get facebook error saying this page isn't working. Unable to handle this request.

i tried encoding location.href through js (encodeURIComponent function) but still it doesn't get affected.

There are ways through fb sdk but i am trying the simpler way.
I am using same on twitter and its working fine. (Twitter url is http://www.twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=).
After searching on internet i am unable to come up with any solution yet.

Also tried opening http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u= and putting url manually. Still i get the error.

Comment: how you are generating the url??

Comment: Hardcoded the first part i.e. FB.com/sharer.... And appending location.href to it using js script @TusharPal

Comment: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=URLENCODED_URL"
   onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');return false;" try this one i have used it
   target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook">
</a>

Comment: this also tried earlier with no luck

Comment: what error are you seeing in console?

Comment: no console error. It is being redirected to fb but fb saying unable to handle this request. Not the fb page but on browser like we get 404 error in chrome. Sometimes its fb page saying something went wrong. we'll get back to it

Comment: please give here the url after clicking on share button

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%3Fhash%3DpfP0Kn1Kzr6brONaf6OJmVUI5cN%2FQMmCM4NNG3h2w7GZYLydrFKfAJVXJvDRfXWpkoKEPxPa3LsPagTesdiJ7w%3D%3D
Currently on localhost but live version is doing same

Comment: shubham something is wrong with url i think it's appending unexpected code as well like hash so Parse it into url using the javascipt function like var uri = "my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURI(uri);

Comment: i encoded whole location.href too but still its getting same error. Is it something to do with locahost also?

Comment: your url is not appriate but suppose if you put google.com come instead of your url it will work.please check

Comment: u are right. its working without encoding url. Can you tell whats wrong with my url?

Comment: firstly its localhost url it's not issue but it's including a hash value which is not appropriate

Comment: actual hash is hash=pfP0Kn1Kzr6brONaf6OJmVUI5cN/QMmCM4NNG3h2w7GZYLydrFKfAJVXJvDRfXWpkoKEPxPa3LsPagTesdiJ7w==

the one i sent is encoded automatically. Whats wrong woth this one

Comment: removing any 1 character from hash nd the fb shre works . Is there anny reason for that. it is clear my url doesnt exceed limits. @TusharPal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no error in setup. But adding additional  tag for og:url which pointed to incorrect url was the problem.
Removing meta tag worked.